# Instagram like app Realm vs CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, android-cursorloader

I have  an instagram like app in which I receive data from a server(imageUrl, username, about) and I store it in a cursorLoader and after that I take the data from the cursorLoader and put it in a RecyclerAdapter. The images are being loaded using the Volley library.

I recently found out about the realm library. Should I use this instead of the cursorLoader ? I'm not even sure why I needed the cursor loader, but I implemented it and it's working. I think I only need to store the user once connected so it doesn't have to connect every time the app is called if he did not disconnect.  Which would be the best approach to make this app work smoothly.

Which is the best way to keep some data displaying like the *instagram/facebook* feed once it was downloaded (even after the user killed the app and turned it on again). Could you give me any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data after they have been downloaded and have it persisted between app restarts, then a database is a good choice. Whether you want to use normal Cursors, some ORM or Realm is really up to what you value and what trade-offs you are willing to accept.

That said, the primary reason for a CursorLoader is to

1. Load a lot of data asynchronously.
2. Hook into change notifications from a ContentProvider

If you don't use a ContentProvider, a CursorLoader looses a lot of its power.

The same functionality a CursorLoader provides (automatic refresh on changes/handle lots of data) can be expressed with far less code using Realm:

```
RealmResults<ServerData> results = realm.where(ServerData.class).findAllAsync();
RealmBaseAdapter adapter = new RealmBaseAdapter(context, results, true);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you. I already implemented this in the meantime with a CursorLoader, but I think I will give realm a shot :D.  As for the login part, is it a good approach to store the user once logged in and check for data everytime the user opens the app  and move him to the control panel ?

Comment: That really depends on your app, so there is no yes or no answer. For non-sensitive data most people would probably prefer that yes.

Comment: What is the other approach ?

Comment: And I do use a Content Provider. Should I stick to it or change everything  for Realm ?

Comment: I cannot answer that question for you, as "it depends". Either approach will work, so I would go with whatever you are most comfortable with instead of looking for "the best". Since you already implemented your ContentProvider/CursorLoader I would probably stick with that.